# Aggregate count per day in excel with open and close dates per record

Tags: excel, pivot, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am trying to find open records in a period of time. i have the open and close table on 1 table but not sure how to aggregate the count and a new table before i can graph out a YoY comparison. see sample data screenshot below and the goal. I am hoping to learn to do in excel and then ill try to replicate in tableau.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be about how to use pivottables. You need open date presumably in rows and also to go in data area as count. Not sure what role closed date plays in any filtering of count? Maybe look at a tutorial such as this: https://peltiertech.com/using-pivot-tables-microsoft-excel/

Comment: The answer is not to use excel.  Sql based method with a date reference table (1 row per date) would let you select date_ref.date, count() from open_close_data join date_ref on date_ref.date >=open_close_data.open_date and date_ref.date <=open_close_data.close_date group by date_ref.date

Comment: SQL is an option, i dont have a calendar table right now, is there any way to generate one easily?

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to achieve this involves restructuring the data**

For datasets with two separate fields or columns with open and close dates the easiest way to enable counts of open or active records is to reformat the data.

Instead of two columns/fields with dates, rewrite the data to have a single field containing dates of events (in this case "open" and "close"). Retain the case ID (or duplicate as many cases will now have two entries: one for open and one for close). Create a new column/field that classified the event (ie case open and case close).

The benefit of doing this is that the number of open cases in a time period is now a matter of counting the case IDs with an open but no close in the period (and adjusting, if you are not starting from zero, for the number open at the start of the time period). If you start a period with no open cases the number open at any time is simply the cumulative total open minus the total closed to that point in time.

The way to achieve the structure is to duplicate parts of the table. Once for the "open" event using the time for that in the new time column and once for the "close" event using the close date in the time column. Not forgetting to add the new column containing the open and close flag for each row.

The data structure should look like this:
[image: ideal structure for data]

Queries on this structure (grouped by even rather than case id) will find it much easier to identify open and closed cases or the total open cases at a given point in time.

Comment: Hi, sorry I cant follow this :(, can you show a preview of the data or attach sample sheet?

Comment: @msulol Added a picture to illustrate the ideal data structure.

Comment: that makes sense @Matt, i have restructured the data. sorry to keep bothering you but based on the picture, can you share the Count formula so it works 1 shot for all records or the sql query? thanks

Comment: here is how i restructured the data in sql: ```select
case,
Opendate as "Date",
cast ('open' as varchar) as event
from table
where enddate is not null
union
select
case,
enddate as "Date",
cast ('closed' as varchar) as event
from table
where enddate is not null```

Comment: The total number of open cases is easy if you convert event type to +1 if 'open' and -1 if 'close'. Then the sum of those numbers is the number of open cases. If you want sums between dates then you also need to keep track of the number opened at the start date, but, basically, the result is a sum of opened-closed cases.

Comment: If your data comes originally with one row per case (and 2 date columns) you can convert to the format above (2 separate rows and 1 date column) in an automated way, such as by using Tableau Prep or Tableau Desktop to union 2 copies of the original data, and adding a calculated field to distinguish open vs close rows